# full page background image resizable - maintain aspect-ratio

Tags: jquery, image, background

I need a simple jquery solution to add a background image to my page filling it entirely, but keeping the aspect ratio and vertical and horizontal centered position.

there are several plugins out here but I don't want to use any plugin.

thanks in advance.

Comment: You know that if a page is long, the image will be unrecognizable because you are keeping the aspect ratio therefore making the image extremely wide.

Comment: my page do not scroll down or right, it is fixed to the browser window. All the content is inside the window limits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code will do what you want..

```
$(function(){

    var stretcher = $('#background-container > img'),
        element = stretcher[0],
        currentSize = { width: 0, height: 0 },
        $document = $(document);

    $(window).resize(function () {
        var w = $document.width();
        var h = $document.height();

        if (currentSize.width != w || currentSize.height != h) {
            stretcher.width(w).height('auto');
            if (h > element.height) {
                stretcher.width('auto').height(h);
            }
            currentSize.width = w;
            currentSize.height = element.width;
        }
    })

    $(window).load(function () {
        $(this).trigger('resize');
    });

});
```

Set your **HTML** like this

```
<div id="page">
    Your page contents here..
</div>
<div id="background-container">
      <img src="path/to/image" />
</div>
```

and your **CSS** like

```
#background-container{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#page{
    position:relative;
    z-index:5;
}
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/3YLQf/

Comment: @ Gaby, is working, thanks, but the image do not get small from certain point, like 800x600 the image doesn't resize down anymore.

Comment: @Emilio, if you want it to scale even when the window is smaller than your content, then change `$document = $(document);` to `$document = $(window);`

Comment: now I need to apply this to an ajaxed image, sorry to bother you, thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean ? you load the image dynamically from script ? if so, you will need to unbind the resize handler, and run this whole script again **once the image has loaded** (*on the image's load handler*)

Answer (score 4):

Or you could use the CSS property :

```
background-size: cover
```

This will scale the image, while preserving its intrinsic aspect ratio (if any), to the smallest size such that both its width and its height can completely cover the background positioning area.

You can control how your image is aligned within the viewport by using the `background-position` property

Comment: Is there also a way to keep the image centered?

Comment: `background-position : 50% 50%` will do it.