# Full Image Background with CSS/jquery or Flash?

Tags: jquery, css, flash

How can I fill my whole background with a big image? The photo is 1400*867 and with the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852949/full-page-background-image-resizable-maintain-aspect-ratio) it fills up the width but not the height. I don't care if the photo gets cropped in order to fill up the height too.

The CSS3 way (background-size) is perfect but doesn't work in IE.

If you don't know a way with css/jquery could you direct me to a flash script where I could just enter the path of the image and let flash resize it?

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this jQuery plugin:

http://nanotux.com/blog/fullscreen/

I think it's what you are looking for; I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot, will check it out and let you know how it goes. :D

Answer (score 1):

You can try [SuperSized](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">

   <!--bg-img-->
   <div class="bg-img>

       <img src="images/bg.jpg"/>

   </div>
   <!--bg-img-->

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.bg-img{
    /*--sets rules to fill browser window in width and height--*/
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 1024px;

    /*--sets proportionate scaling--*/
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;

    /*--positioning and layering of image container--*/
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index:-5;
}
```

I believe the CSS3 method you speak of is something like this?:

```
.bg-img{
    background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Well, there is a work around for IE that you can try but it's not foolproof. You can try changing the entire snippet to this instead:

```
.bg-img{
    /*--CSS3 compatible browsers setup--*/
    background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;

    /*--work around for IE--*/
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.bg.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='bg.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
}
```

Good luck! Hope it works!